# React is somehow calling a setState that modify my data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have dynamic data that is so supposed to change when i change "period" hook. I only call "setPeriod" hook in an onclick button, but somehow, it seems that React is calling "setPeriod" in an unknown place, since my data change when i change the value of  my input, which is undesirable effect.
In the first place, i want "ephemeralData" to store the data of my inputs, and then i want "applyHandler" function to call "setPeriod" hook and to pass "ephemeralData" as argument, so my dynamic text changes. Can't figure out why it's not working

```
    const [period, setPeriod] = useState([
        {
            day: 'Lundi',
            startHour: 0,
            endHour: 1
        },
        {
            day: 'Mardi',
            startHour: 0,
            endHour: 1
        },
        {
            day: 'Mercredi',
            startHour: 0,
            endHour: 1
        },
        {
            day: 'Jeudi',
            startHour: 0,
            endHour: 1
        },
        {
            day: 'Vendredi',
            startHour: 0,
            endHour: 1
        },
        {
            day: 'Samedi',
            startHour: 0,
            endHour: 1
        },
        {
            day: 'Dimanche',
            startHour: 0,
            endHour: 1
        },
    ])
    const [ephemeralData, setEphemeralData] = useState([
        {
            day: 'Lundi',
            startHour: 0,
            endHour: 1
        },
        {
            day: 'Mardi',
            startHour: 0,
            endHour: 1
        },
        {
            day: 'Mercredi',
            startHour: 0,
            endHour: 1
        },
        {
            day: 'Jeudi',
            startHour: 0,
            endHour: 1
        },
        {
            day: 'Vendredi',
            startHour: 0,
            endHour: 1
        },
        {
            day: 'Samedi',
            startHour: 0,
            endHour: 1
        },
        {
            day: 'Dimanche',
            startHour: 0,
            endHour: 1
        },
    ])

    const hours = ['minuit', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23];
   
    const [options, setOptions] = useState(['period', 'period', 'period', 'period', 'period', 'period', 'period']);
 

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const { value } = e.target
        setState({
            ...state,
            [event.target.name] : value
        })
    }

   

    const deletePeriodHandler = (index) => {
        let newArr = [...options];
        newArr[index] = 'fullyAvailable'
        setOptions(newArr)
        let newPeriod = [...period]
        newPeriod[index][startHour] = 0
        newPeriod[index][endHour] = 0
        setPeriod(newPeriod)
 
        
    }

    const blockDayHandler = (index) => {
        let newArr = [...options];
        newArr[index] = 'unavailable'
        setOptions(newArr)
        
    }

    const handleEphemeralChangePeriod = (index, e) => {
        let {value} = e.target
        if (value === 'minuit') value = 0
        let newArr = [...ephemeralData]
        newArr[index][e.target.name] = value
        setEphemeralData(newArr)

    }

    const applyHandler = (index) => {
        let newArr = [...options];
        newArr[index] = 'period'
        setOptions(newArr)
        let newData = [...ephemeralData]
        setPeriod(newData)

    }

return (

[SHORTENED CODE NOT TO BOTHER YOU ! ]

<div className={classes.AccordionsContainer}>
                {period.map((element, index) => {

                     
                    return  <div className={classes.Accordion} key={index}>
                                <Card>
                                    
                                    <Collapse isOpen={isAccordionOpen[index]} data-parent="#accordion" id="collapseOne" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                                        <CardBody>
                                            Vos horaires de disponibilités le {element.day}
                                            <div className={classes.HoursAndDeleteButtonContainer}>
                                                {
                                                    (() => {
                                                        if (options[index] === 'period' )
                                                            return <>
                                                                <span className={classes.Period}>De {period[index].startHour} h à {period[index].endHour} h</span>
                                                                <div className={classes.DeleteButton} onClick={()=>deletePeriodHandler(index)}>supprimer</div>
                                                            </>
                                                        if (options[index] === 'fullyAvailable')
                                                            return <span className={classes.FullyAvaialable}>Vous êtes disponible toute la journée</span>
                                                        else (options[index] === 'unavailable')
                                                            return <span className={classes.Unavailable}>INDISPONIBLE</span>
                                                    })()
                                                }
                                                
                                            </div>
                                            <hr />
                                            <div className={classes.HandleChangePeriodContainer}>
                                                <p className={classes.AddPeriodParagraph}>Ajouter des horaires de disponibilité</p>
                                                <div className={classes.InputPeriodContainer}>
                                                    <div>De</div>
                                                    <Input
                                                        type="select"
                                                        name="startHour"
                                                        id="startHour"
                                                        className={classes.AccordionInput}
                                                        onChange={(e)=>handleEphemeralChangePeriod(index, e)}
                                                        value={ephemeralData[index].startHour}
                                                    >
                                                        
                                                        {hours.map((element, index) => {
                                                            return <option key={index}>{element}</option>
                                                        })}
                                                    </Input>
                                                    <div>à</div>
                                                    <Input
                                                        type="select"
                                                        name="endHour"
                                                        id="endHour"
                                                        className={classes.AccordionInput}
                                                        onChange={(e)=>handleEphemeralChangePeriod(index, e)}
                                                        value={ephemeralData[index].endHour}
                                                    >
                                                        
                                                        {hours.map((element, index) => {
                                                            return <option key={index}>{element}</option>
                                                        })}
                                                    </Input>
                                                    <div className={classes.SubmitButton} onClick={()=>applyHandler(index)}>Appliquer</div>
                                                    <div className={classes.BlockDay} onClick={() => blockDayHandler(index)}>Bloquer la journée</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            
                                        </CardBody>
                                    </Collapse>
                                </Card> 
                            </div>
                        
                })}
            </div>

)
```

Comment: That's still a whole lot of code to try and read through. Can you try and reduce it to a minimal example?

Comment: Something that sticks out is that you're doing shallow copies (`let newArr = [...ephemeralData]`), but modifying nested values in there (`newArr[index][e.target.name] = value`) which may result in non-obvious things happening.

Comment: @AKX Reduced the code to the minimalist example i could find. I thought that making shallow copies and worcking on them was the way to do in ReactJs

Comment: You're making a shallow copy of the first level of the array, but mutating _another_ object within it you're _not_ copying at all. You'd also need to `newArr[index] = {...newArr[index], [e.target.name]: value}`.

Comment: Well thanks your answer solved my problem. I can't understand why though. Really strange behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was to copy the deeper level of my nested object, as AKX suggested.

```
const handleEphemeralChangePeriod = (index, e) => {
        let {value} = e.target
        if (value === 'minuit') value = 0
        let newArr = [...ephemeralData]
        newArr[index] = {...newArr[index], [e.target.name]: value}
        setEphemeralData(newArr)
    }
```